# Mocking react-router-dom hooks using jest is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I'm using Enzyme's shallow method to test a component which uses the `useParams` hook to get an ID from the URL params.

I'm trying to mock the `useParams` hook so that it does't call the actual method, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`, so it calls the actual `useParams`, and not my mock.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => {

  const { id } = useParams();

  return <div>{id}</div>;

};
```

Test:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Header />', () => {

  jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: '123' }),
  }));

  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

This works for me to mock useParams and change values for each unit test within the same file:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Router from "react-router-dom";
import Component from "./Component";

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
 ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
 useParams: jest.fn(),
}));

const createWrapper = () => {
 return render(<Cases />);
};

describe("Component Page", () => {
 describe("Rendering", () => {
   it("should render cases container", () => {
     jest.spyOn(Router, 'useParams').mockReturnValue({ id: '1234' })
     const wrapper = createWrapper();
     expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
   });

   it("should render details container", () => {
     jest.spyOn(Router, 'useParams').mockReturnValue({ id: '5678' })
     const wrapper = createWrapper();
     expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
   });
 });
});
```

Just declare `useParams` as `jest.fn()` outside describe() and then change its values in each unit test with `jest.spyOn`

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me after migrating to v6 from @reach/router.

Comment: Thank you very much, phenomenon, crack, galactic, god, mastodon, giant, monster

Comment: note that `Router` is imported via default import here (without `{}`).

Comment: @messerbill this saved me! The default behavior in VS Code when using the Quick Fix action to import `Router` is to import as `import { Router } from "react-router-dom"` but this will fail. It must be `import Router from "react-router-dom"` as @messerbill stated

Comment: The key thing is definitely to define the `.mock` part with `jest.fn()` outside of test suites, and then do `spyOn`.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure why, also couldn't find it in the docs of react-router library, but changing `react-router-dom` to `react-router` in both tests and implementation worked for me.

So it becomes something like this:

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Header />', () => {

  jest.mock('react-router', () => ({
    useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: '123' }),
  }));

  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @ivan, If someone knows the logic behind it please post it here.

Comment: Well I think I found it: `react-router-dom` does not define hooks. Hooks are defined in `react-router` package. Therefore if you want to mock react router hooks, you will need to mock that package. See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/index.js

Comment: Even when I import those hooks from react-router and mock the react-router package, it still gives em the same error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: If you're going to call `jest.mock` on `react-router` for the purpose of mocking `useParams`, it's probably a good idea to include everything else before the `useParams` mock by adding `...jest.requireActual('react-router')`. This ensures that the rest of `react-router` doesn't get lost.

Answer (score 8):

I've had a similar problem, I solved it like this:

```
import { Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";

const renderWithRouter = (component) => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: ["/part1/idValue1/part2/idValue2/part3"],
  });
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/part1/:id1/part2/:id2/part3">{children}</Route>
    </Router>
  );
  return {
    ...render(component, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
    history,
  };
};

describe("test", () => {
  it("test desc", async () => {
    const { getByText } = renderWithRouter(<MyComponent/>);
    expect(getByText("idValue1")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using react-testing-library but I hope the router part at least is  similar

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I tried this mock but it doesn't work to me. Error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. It seems the component is not inside a router so it cannot mock the match with params. It works to me:

```
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const RenderWithRouter = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['uri/Ineed']}>
    <Route path="route/Ineed/:paramId">{children}</Route>
  </MemoryRouter>
);
const tf = new TestFramework();
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  tf.init({ title: 'Some test' }, props =>
    shallow(
      <RenderWithRouter>
        <MyComponent {...props} />
      </RenderWithRouter>
    )
  );

  it('Some description', () => {
    const wrapper = tf.render().html();
    expect(wrapper).toContain('something');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing to add other keys of `react-router-dom` as is.

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: '123' })
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me mocking react-router-dom fix the issue:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ nifUuid: 'nif123' }),
    useHistory: jest.fn()
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I mocked useParams like this:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  return {
    useParams: () => ({
      id: '123'
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I mocked useParams like this before describe

```
const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual("react-router-dom") as any),
  useNavigate: () => mockedNavigate,
  useParams: () => ({
    id: 223250 
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what worked for me:

```
let mockUseParams;
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useParams: jest.fn(() => mockUseParams),
}));

beforeEach(() => mockUseParams = undefined;)

test('MyComponent uses a param', () => {
    mockUseParams = { id: 'testId' };
    render(<MyComponent />);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `setupTests.js`

```js
export const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
export const mockHistoryGoBack = jest.fn();
export const mockHistoryReplace = jest.fn();
export const mockLocation = jest.fn();
export let mockUseParams = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush,
    replace: mockHistoryReplace,
    goBack: mockHistoryGoBack,
  }),
  useLocation: () => mockLocation,
  useParams: mockUseParams,
}));
```

and when I want to use it and change it per test, I do

```js
mockUseParams.mockReturnValue({id: 42});
```

in each of the tests.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
Calling the "cleanup" function from the "@testing-library/react" helps me:

```
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
});
```

Comment: In general providing steps that helped you come to this solution can be very useful to others if you their fix is not exactly the same as yours, that aside, nice clean answer.